# mysql index optimization problem

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a query like below.

```
SELECT a,b,c,d 
FROM table_name  
WHERE e=1 AND f=0 
GROUP BY d 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

when I indexed (e,f,d) query time : 4 sec.

when I indexed (d,e,f) query time : 20 sec.

So that I understand that index colums ordering is important.
Which index would be better for mysql?

Comment: I don't understand a little: you are grouping by **d** and then you are trying to sort everything by **id**. But the problem is that **id** is undefined in this case. So I believe the query can't use the index for sorting. Your query is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes should first satisfy the where clause, then the group or order clause. Always use `EXPLAIN` on your query to see how it is performed

Comment: when I indexed (e,f,d) query time : 4 sec.
4 sec. is not long for this query? i have 500.000 records.

Comment: show output of `EXPLAIN`. See how query performs without order by or without group by. Usually group by creates temporary tables and is much slower. But still 4 seconds is too much.

Comment: id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE table_name ref index_2,index,index_3,index_4,index_5 index_5 2 const,const 493261 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: without group and order  Query took 0.0008 sec.

Comment: only with group Query took 0.0014 sec
only with order Query took 4.0751 sec

i think order section is occure slow.

Comment: it have to sort 500 000 records. Add id to the index. Btw, how many total rows there are in the table (500 000 are those with e=1 and f=0), and what is your storage engine?

Comment: my table is myisam
only e=1 and f=0 result 523,473 total, Query took 0.0009 sec
whitout any where 672,276 total.
i added id to the index but it is name 
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
Showing rows 0 - 4 (5 total, Query took 4.7143 sec) [id: 1447145 - 1446420]